# DataGrid information throwing out 'Object Reference' error.

Tags: vb.net

So. I looked around Stackoverflow before posting this question. I found other Questions, but none of them answered my question.

This is my code:

```
Sub getData()
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Dim rowindex As String
    Dim found As Boolean = False
    Dim actie As String
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.Cells.Item("Column1").Value.ToString.Contains("2014-0" & Date.Today.Month.ToString) Then
            rowindex = row.Index.ToString()
            found = True
            actie = row.Cells("Column2").Value.ToString()
            ListBox1.Items.Add(actie)
        End If
    Next
    If Not found Then
        MsgBox("Item not found")
    End If
End Sub
```

What this does is calls data from a DataGrid. The issue I am having is on 'ListBox1.items.add(actie)'. If I use a Message Box it works fine until I get to the last one and then it also throws the error. (That'll likely be why it throws the error straight away for the ListBox as it adds them all 'at the same time'). I've tried an 'ELSE' but with the else it just says no data found. I thought a Do Until might have worked but it did not.

Error I am getting is: Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object.

I assume this is going to be something really basic and I'm going to hit myself when I turns out to be extremely basic.

Comment: can the user add data thru a blank row at the end (`AllowuserToAddRows`)?  These errors are all the same: you have something that is not initialized: using the mouse you can hold it over variables to see which one it is

Comment: @Plutonix the only data the user can add is via the .CSV file. Like, I know what is causing the error. It's when it gets to the end of the data, basically when it can't find anymore, it's just crashing.

Comment: the default for `.AllowUsersToAddRows` is true if you didnt change it then the last row is nothing, Cells("Column2") will be nothing, as a result actiee will be nothing and somewhere you'll get the NullReferenceException

Comment: @Plutonix I see! I added 'DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False' to the start of the Subroutine and it actually fixed it. You're great, thank you!

Comment: you can also test the row using the `IsNewRow` property in cases where you do need to allow the user to add new rows. Set `AllowUserToAddRows` in the design props window - select the control on the form and tap F4